# react-router-dom Failed prop type: Invalid prop `exact` of type `string`

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I met some strange warning when I try to use `<Route />` component. Please pay your attention into a line `<Route exact={"true"} .../>` which makes strange browser warnings described beneath code sample.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={appStore}>
        <ConnectedRouter store={appStore} history={history}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={"true"} path="/" component={App}/>
                    <Route render={() => <h1>404, not found</h1>} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ConnectedRouter>
   </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Browser console says me next:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `exact` of type `string`
>   supplied to `Route`, expected `boolean`.
>       in Route (at src/index.tsx:19) index.js:1452

And the following warning after prev one is absolutely apposite by text logic

> Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`.
>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead:
>   exact="true" or exact={value.toString()}.
>       in a (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Link (at App.tsx:25)
>       in header (at App.tsx:11)
>       in div (at App.tsx:10)
>       in App (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Route (at src/index.tsx:19)
>       in Switch (at src/index.tsx:18)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (at src/index.tsx:17)
>       in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
>       in ConnectedRouter (at src/index.tsx:16)
>       in Provider (at src/index.tsx:15)

[image: react-router-dom Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'exact' of type 'string']
Could you please help me with this issue. Tnx!

described example are located here in opensource prj https://github.com/gyerts/react/blob/master/starters/typescript-scss-redux/src/index.tsx#L19

Comment: Are you passing exact attribute to a Link element too?

Comment: Which react router version are you using?

Comment: `"react-router": "^4.3.1"`,
    `"react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.6"`,
    `"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9"`,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that for some unexplained reason I've passed attribute `exact` to a Link component.

```
<Link exact to="/about">About the author</Link>
```

So I removed `exact` attribute and warning is gone.

```
<Link to="/about">About the author</Link>
```

Comment: You should also change your route to this `<Route exact path="/" component={App} />` if the prop exact is not there router will assume it's false. You don't have to do `exact={"true"}` or `exact={"false"}` just do `exact` or don't put it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use exact. You don't have to remove it.

Just like this:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={appStore}>
     <ConnectedRouter store={appStore} history={history}>
         <BrowserRouter>
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}/>
                 <Route render={() => <h1>404, not found</h1>} />
            </Switch>
         </BrowserRouter>
    </ConnectedRouter>
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can pass `true` to it. it can solve your problem. You don't have to remove `exact`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `exact` attribute without its value like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
```

Comment: can't accept your answer because this tells me the second warning described in the question `Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`.`

Comment: what if `<Route exact="true"`

Comment: this variant I also tried, but the issue was in other place. So you answer and comment are correct, but not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try, ***exact={true}***. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can also give it a `boolean` value like mentioned below:

```
<Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}/>
```

Or without any value as when you just write attribute, considered as true (default value is true)

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
```

it worked for me.